# how to make Jest continue to run after fail case in expect

Tags: jestjs

When I run this code, the test stops on its first failure case and I was wondering how I can get it to continue going after failure until it completely iterates over the array:

```
it('b contains all elements in a', () => {
  const a = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd'];
  const b = ['e', 'f', 'g', 'i'];
  for (let i = 0; i < a.length; i += 1) {
    expect(b).toContain(a[i]);
  }
});
```

Comment: Why do you want to continue your test when it failed?

Comment: if you just want to see _full_ difference you better use [`toMatchObject`](https://jestjs.io/docs/en/expect#tomatchobjectobject) or compose [custom matcher](https://jestjs.io/docs/en/expect#expectextendmatchers) if your jest's version does not support `toMatchObject` out of the box. there is no way to stop jest from failing.